# Solving a polynomial equation with an approximate constraint is slower than the symbolic solution

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation

Why do these two operations have such different timing, when the only difference is specifying `r` as approximate $0.1$ vs arbitrary-precision $1/10$?

Here are the definitions of my polynomial:

```
z[0, c_] := c
z[n_, c_] := z[n - 1, c]^2 + c;
expr = Expand[z[8, c] - z[4, c]];
```

And here I try to find roots that obey to a certain constraint. The difference is in how I express the constraint, i.e. as an approximate vs. arbitrary-precision quantity.

```
r = .1;
AbsoluteTiming[approx = c /. Solve[{expr == 0, Abs[c - I] < r}, c];]

r = 1/10;
AbsoluteTiming[symbolic = c /. Solve[{expr == 0, Abs[c - I] < r}, c];]

(* Out:
{12.2965, Null}
{0.429137, Null}
*)
```

Of course the two solutions are equivalent:

```
Sort[approx] == Sort[N[symbolic]]

(* Out: True *)
```

I don't understand why the symbolic computation is that much faster than the one with the approximate constraint.

On the other hand, `NSolve` can't seem to cope with this equation at all, whether the constraint is approximate or arbitrary-precision:

```
r = .1;
NSolve[{expr == 0, Abs[c - I] < r}, c]
(* Out: {} *)

r = 1/10;
NSolve[{expr == 0, Abs[c - I] < r}, c]
(* Out: {} *)
```

Can you help me understand these puzzling behaviors?

Comment: Additional detail: the problem persists if you get rid of the `15` argument to `N`. Additionally, converting `N[Solve[…]]` to `NSolve[…]` causes Mathematica to output no solutions at all.

Comment: @Kuba  I see that, but I don't know how to interpret it.  When we include the N, the two methods gets identical results, one just takes far longer.

Comment: @Kuba  I don't think that's what's going on.  If you test aa==bb, it returns True, implying same precision.

Comment: This still does not explain why one method takes so much longer when they both come to the same result, same precision.

Comment: @Kuba You may be operating under a misunderstanding here: the *symbolic* solution is MUCH faster in this case, not the approximate one. The numerical solution is an order of magnitude slower. That's the crux of the problem. All the discussion about `N` is irrelevant.

Comment: @JerryGuern I edited your question to try and highlight your point. The edits are rather heavy, so please feel free to revert anything that does not represent your original point.

Comment: @MarcoB you are right.

Comment: @MarcoB  Thanks for the help on communicating my point.  I've been sing MMa only about a year, and I still feel like I don't understand its inner working well enough to describe the puzzling things it does.